# Start activity for result not work, between different activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the main page where the photo is loaded, depending on what the array on the other page contains, in order to synchronize them I used StartActivityForResult();.

It will works like this: MainActivity  has a photo, i press showMore button(open showMoreActivity), at showMoreActivity change text and after i finish showMoreActivity, MainActivity load the new photo depends on new text, but real it doesn`t change photo.

Can you help me? Where the mistake is?

```
        buttonShowMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowMore.class);
            onStop();
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }



    });
```

onClick button ShowMore Listener

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}

    String dataStringExtra =data.getStringExtra("name1");

    Picasso.get().load(  dataStringExtra + ".jpg").into(imageViewFirstOfCurrentList);


}
```

onActivityResult method

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("name1", List.get(0).toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

when close showMore Activity

[image: representation]

Comment: I forgot include super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

Answer (score 0):

try removing call to onStop() in your onClick() method

Comment: it doesn`t help(

Comment: WHy are you passing 0th item always in the array? intent.putExtra("name1", List.get(0).toString());, You should pass selected image, at whatever index it is

Comment: because, the quantity of images can be more than 1

Comment: i found the mistake, i forgot 
include         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);